# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function after hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below recognizes the hover function but right after it, the console shows an error: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hider").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hide");
    },function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hide");

    });
});
</script>
```

Any suggestion on where is the error?

Comment: Could you be more specific @Shomz?

Comment: You didn't include the library jQuery before executing that code.

Comment: jQuery library isn't included or the document function is called before the jquery library

Comment: I did, just edited the quieston.

Comment: you need to mention mouseover.. in place of hover...

Comment: Can you create a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) with minimum code which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score -1):

As odd as it looks. This works:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hider").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("hide");
    },function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("hide");

    });
});
```

I still have no idea what I'm doing or why it works.

Comment: Your original code also works, as long as jQuery is present (I just tested it in a snippet just to be sure; it's fine.)

Comment: Thanks @DanielBeck, I'm still not sure why it wasn't working with the `$` inside my webpage.